# Continued gameplay after beating Contra

Tags: contra

I just beat the original Contra on NES. After the ending credits finished scrolling, the game took me back to the first level, with the number of lives I had accumulated during play. Are there any differences in gameplay if you continue playing after beating the game, or is it just a big loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have beaten Contra during my childhood 2 times in a row, and i have noticed a little change. If you take a look at [Gaming Forums](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/563399-contra/71398082), you will see reports that the game gets harder after beating.

*LukeInside* user reported after beating the 3rd time:

> On the third round the amount of troopers is increased and their
>   running/shooting speed is faster so watch out. I wonder how far can a
>   player get before the game becomes unforgiving :) I'm on Snow level
>   now and on third walkthrough. What are your experiences with that
>   classic game?

User *Damon Plus*, reported that after the 5th time, things slow down a little on difficulty progression, but you will still see some hard to kill mobs:

> I got 7 games straight through the game, and I finally died at the
>   mid-boss of the 8th level. After about the 5th time, difficulty
>   doesn't increase anymore, but if you die, you're screwed. Every boss
>   takes forever to kill. I died because the flying yellow things he
>   trows absorbed a lot more bullets that I could shoot before they
>   overwhelmed me.

What we can get after reading this reports is that:

- Bosses will need more damage to be killed;
- Enemies that require more than 1 shot to kill, will need more damage to be killed;
- Amount of enemies(specially troopers) will increase;
- Shots will be faster;
- Spawn points for troopers will be less predictable;
- Max points is 6553500 and [you will get at the 8th run](http://nintendoage.com/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=31&threadid=63128)(*jonebone* post);

<strike>Take a look at the following video: [Contra After Beating the Game 100 (One Hundred) Times in a Row](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icoRqalbJhI)</strike> - *Link is broken and i could not find any other streaming service with it uploaded, unfortunately*.

You can see at this link what happens at the [8th loop of Nes Contra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cX6kFdNoPIE). Besides the quality of the video(7 years old) look at how much the difficulty increases. And at the [12th loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szGQWeqFaFk) in the last stage, you can't kill the "[flying scorpions](http://contra.wikia.com/wiki/Bugger)(Bugger)" just by spamming shots while running through the stage.

Comment: Video link not working for me.

Comment: Not working for me too. Are you having an issue where it only shows an exclamation mark?

Comment: Yep, same issue here.  I checked thinking it was work but other vids work for me, same problem at home.

Comment: Tried to find this same video everywere but found no alternative on other hosting sites. Sorry :(

Comment: I actually made my comment in case you wanted to remove it=)  I already +1ed you, good writeup.